# Error while parsing xml attribute

Tags: xml-parsing

I am getting error on

```
I.ID=((Element) nl.item(i)).getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue();
```

the error is that

> getNamedItem required INT and found String

When i give an Int value then the error said that it required String and found Int.

Comment: Which language, C#? Also, it would be better, if you could provide any Code/Sample XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

getNamedItem is returning String value while ID is an integer value. so i put string to integer parser which resolved my issue.